# GPU Shaders for Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, gpu

How are shaders used in deep learning? Based on what I've researched online, it seems shaders are only used for drawing shadows in computer graphics.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I've modified it!

Answer (score 4):

The key insight is that traditionally GPUs write pixels to 2D array of pixels. What are pixels? They're just values. So really a GPU writes values that you ask it to compute using shaders to a 2D array of values. Stop thinking of these values as pixels and start thinking of them as the results of a math equation and you can use GPUs to compute certain kinds of math very quickly.

Traditionally GPUs access 2D arrays of values via textures. You fill 1 or more textures with your input data. That data can be 1D, 2D or 3D or of course you can use more math to convert indices of larger dimensional data back into any of those 1D, 2D, or 3D textures

The fact that originally GPUs did this to draw triangles using pixels is arguably an accident of history.  Pixels are just values in a 2D arrays. It just took a while for people to stop thinking of them as only pixels.

An an example let's add 2 arrays of numbers using the GPU using WebGL

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const ext = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
if (!ext) alert('need OES_texture_float');

// the data
const a = new Float32Array([12, 34, 56, 78, 90]);
const b = new Float32Array([11, 22, 33, 44, 55]);

const numElements = a.length;

const vs = `
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0,0,0,1);
  gl_PointSize = float(${numElements});
}`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D aTex;
uniform sampler2D bTex;
void main() {
  vec4 a = texture2D(aTex, gl_PointCoord.xy);  // get value from array a
  vec4 b = texture2D(bTex, gl_PointCoord.xy);  // get value from array b
  gl_FragColor = a + b;                        // write the result
}`;

// compile the shaders to do the math
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// create a 5x1 RGBA texture to store the results
const fbi = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, [
  { type: gl.FLOAT, minMag: gl.NEAREST, wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, },
], numElements, 1);
twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, fbi);

// copy the data to textures
const aTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: a,
  width: numElements,
  format: gl.LUMINANCE,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});
const bTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: b,
  width: numElements,
  format: gl.LUMINANCE,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

// tell the GPU to use this shader
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

// bind the texture and tell the shader where to find them
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
  aTex,
  bTex,
});

// draw numElements size pixel point which will result in
// numElement values being computed
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

// read the result (it's RGBA but we only care about R)
const result = new Float32Array(numElements * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, numElements, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, result);

for (let i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
  console.log(`${a[i]} + ${b[i]} = ${result[i * 4]}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see the GPU just added 2 arrays of data. Adding and multiplying arrays are pretty much the core of machine learning.

[tensorflow can use WebGL in the browser](https://www.tensorflow.org/js).

If you'd like to learn WebGL consider [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org). They don't do much non-graphics stuff but will hopefully explain how the GPU works. The knowledge is pretty much the same regardless of API (WebGL/DirectX/OpenGL/Vulkan/Metal)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed comment! So the purpose of shaders is basically to manipulate vectors of data? How is that different from a float16 multiplier then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a `float16` multiplier. The difference is [a top GPU](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-2080-ti.c3305) has > 3000 cores so it can compute 3000+ values in parallel. That's *potentially* a 3000x increase over a single CPU